# Get rid of ActionBar shadow over SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, shadow, android-appcompat

I'm porting my app to appcompat21, using SlidingTabLayout for tabs in an ActionBarActivity. The Action bar is casting a shadow over the tab strip, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it:[image]

Here's what I have:

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
     <item name="background">@color/app_primary</item>
     <item name="android:background">@color/app_primary</item>
     <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/black</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/black</item>
     <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
 </style>
```

I've also tried

```
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

I got the shadow *under* the tab bar by setting its elevation in the layout file, but now I have two shadows...
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason, this did not work for as well:

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

and:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

I am currently using, for `ActionBar`:

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Let me know if you run into any weird combinations with `android:elevation` and `android:windowContentOverlay`. I just ended up commenting those out in my `styles.xml`.

Comment: I'd like to know why setting elevation through layout doesn't work. I had that issue.

Answer (score 2):

When working with "Elevation", objects can be different elevations from one another, giving shadows to anything underneath them.

If you set your toolbar and the tabs layout the same elevation it will fix the issue.

Comment: Mine are the same elevation and it is still showing shadows

Answer (score 1):

Add `app:elevation="0dp"` on `.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try putting

```html
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
```

without the "android:", this would spare you the pain of setting the elevation every time you start an activity